# Correct way to set ports with iptables

Tags: iptables

I'd like optimize my iptables script setting to variable the list of ports:

```
# allowed services
PORTS=21,22,23

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports $PORTS -j ACCEPT
```

is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think you could put variables in the iptables.conf. In the past when this was needed I would create a bash script wrapped around iptables to create/update needed values within iptables.

Comment: Yes, he can't do it, because the shell variables are interpreted only by the shell. However, I am not sure that this is from an iptables.conf, it looks more like being part of a shell script.